# Which are all the known "joke items" that Fred & George created throughout HP History?

Tags: harry-potter

Fred and George seem to have created a wide range of gag gifts and practical joke items, both while at Hogwarts and then as owners of their "*Wizard Wheezes*" emporium.

**What are all the known "jokes items" that Fred & George created throughout HP History and what were their side-effects?**